# Define a templated T as pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to define some generic pointer (? but not a void pointer) using this code:

```
class A
{

template<typename T>
using ptr = T*;

using ubyte = uint8_t;

public:

    const ptr<ubyte>
    getColor1() const {
        return &colors[0];
    }

    const ubyte*
    getColor2() const {
        return &colors[0];
    }


private:

    ubyte colors[4];
};
```

However, the `getColor1()` won't compile.
What's the difference between this two functions ?

gcc says:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const ubyte* {aka const unsigned char*}' to 'A::ptr<unsigned char> {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]|
```

**Update:**

The deleted answer says I could do this:

```
//option 1
template<typename T>
using const_ptr = const T*;
```

or

```
//option 2
const ptr<ubyte>
getColor()  //remove cv-qualifier
{
    return &colors[0];
}
```

From option1,

It constructs now to `const const`, what does `const const` means?

From option2,

Why just removing cv-qualifier makes this compile?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I put the error message in my post.

Comment: Option 2 makes it compile, but does not do what you want. It returns a const pointer to a non-const ubyte, but you can't assign a new pointer to the return value anyway so that const is relatively useless :)

Comment: @AndrewTomazos yeah I think we've established that much :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const ptr<ubyte>` is the same as `const (ubyte *)` which is *not* the same as `const ubyte (*)`. You are trying to return a `const` pointer to a non-const `char`, which the compiler won't allow because you've declared the function itself `const`; all members become `const` because of that. The compiler won't automatically cast const to non-const without a `const_cast`.

To make the difference clearer, the first is a const pointer to a non-const `char` and the second is a non-const pointer to a const `char`. The first allows the pointed-to characters to change, even though the pointer itself can't change. Since the function was marked as `const` it can't return anything that would allow its members to be modified.

The best way to fix it:

```
ptr<const ubyte>
getColor1() const {
    return &colors[0];
}
```

Comment: `const (ubyte *)` is not a valid type-id.  You mean `ubyte* const`.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos, actually I think I mean `ubyte (* const)`: http://ideone.com/GQy6yx. I *hate* C/C++ syntax for pointers and type modifiers, it's not intuitive at all.

Comment: `ubyte* const` and `ubyte (* const)` are equivalent, the parenthesis are redundant: See http://ideone.com/iCeYcz  Yes, C++ declarator precedence takes some time to learn.  Search for the "spiral rule".

Comment: @AndrewTomazos, I know the parentheses are redundant but I was trying to make a point. That point being where the `const` was being applied.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the syntax of your `ptr` template, `const ptr<ubyte>` first makes it a `ubyte*`, then applies the const, resulting in a `ubyte * const`, a constant pointer to an ubyte.

In order to return a pointer to a const ubyte, you need to feed a `const ubyte` into your pointer template, so constness is applied first:

```
ptr<const ubyte>
```

Answer (score 1):

1)  "what does const const means?"

```
const T* const pT = new T;
```

Means const pointer pT - you cannot assign pT to another object;
to a const object of type T - you cannot change the object which is pointed by pT.

2) "Why just removing cv-qualifier makes this compile?"

```
getColor1()
```

method without [const modifier](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-member-fns.html) can modify the object. It now returns A::ubyte* which can be converted to a const type such as declared as return type: A::ubyte* const  (const ptr< ubyte > )

Comment: That isn't valid.  You mean `const T* const pT`.

Comment: I mean `const const T*`, not the one with `cv-qualifier`

Comment: `T*`, `const T*`, `T* const` and `const T* const` are all valid and distinct types.  `const const T*` is not valid.

Comment: But how does this one constructs then `const const_ptr<ubyte> const`?

Comment: @mr5 like `const ptr<const ubyte>`

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Ah, okay then, I thought it was two consecutive `const` :D